# why does ctx.fillRect() executed only after the for loop is over?

Tags: javascript

I want to build a basic function where an Object (Rectangle) is painted, it's x coordinate is changed and than painted again. However, when I execute my code nothing happens until my for loop is over and than everything gets executed at the same time.

```js
ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

class Car{
 constructor(options){
  this.pos = options.pos;
  this.size = options.size;
  this.color = options.color;
}

draw(){
 ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
 ctx.fillRect(this.pos[0], this.pos[1], this.size[0], this.size[1]);
}

move(){
 this.pos[0] = this.pos[0] + 10;
 }
}

const audi = new Car({pos: [10,10], size: [300,20], color: "red"});

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
 do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function drawAndMove(){
 audi.draw();
 audi.move();
 sleep(1000);
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 20);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
 drawAndMove();
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead of blocking main thread

Comment: Because that `sleep` blocks the script.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Maybe you can help me with something else. Is there a way to clear the rectangle without giving it's coordinates? just clear any rectangle on the screen. or every rectangle with the same Id or st

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use sleep(1000) all the script is paused.

Javascript is single threaded language that mean the code is executed synchronously line after line, if you want to make thing append later than they should be, use `setTimeout` than `sleep()`

like that :

```js
function drawAndMove(){
  audi.draw();
  audi.move();
  setTimeout(() => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 20);
  }, 1000);

}
```

By this way the code will continue to run sidedly and the script wont be paused !

Comment: that work's perfectly. thank you so much. I have one question tho. Is there a way to clear the rectangle without giving it's coordinates? just clear any rectangle on the screen. or every rectangle with the same Id or sth

Comment: you can't without giving coordinates i guess, but for your code you can just store the previous coordinates of the rectangle and height and width and every time you move it you clear the rectangle and then set new previous coordinates ?